# Updating post_parent by id (many times)

Tags: wp-update-post

How can I update `post_parent` by ids?

I tried:

```
add_action('init','updating_parent');

function updating_parent(){

    $args = array(
       'post__in' => array(208,51) 
    );

    $my_posts = get_posts( $args );

    foreach ( $my_posts as $my_post ):

        $my_post['post_parent'] = 12;

        wp_update_post( $my_post );

    endforeach;
}
```

But this is not working. But even it wouldn't be what I need. Since I have data like:

```
ID => post_parent
208 => 12
51 => 19
and so on...
```

So I need an array at `post_parent` as well.

Comment: If you want achieve the same. Use SQL:
INSERT INTO wp_posts (id,post_parent) VALUES (208,12),(51,19)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE post_parent=VALUES(post_parent);

Answer (score 1):

A post can only ever have one parent post.

I'm certain you can still accomplish what you want using post meta, though. If you give us a better explanation of what you're trying to do we might be able to help.

For example,

```
function updating_parent() {
    // your code to get posts

    foreach ( $my_posts as $post ) {
        update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'related_posts', array( 12, 23, 42 ) );
    }
}
```

Then you can access this data using `get_post_meta`:

```
$related_posts = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'related_posts', true );
```

Comment: Sorry for not beeing clear. I just wanted one parent_post. But I understood now, that it's much easier to achieve with SQL:
INSERT INTO wp_posts (id,post_parent) VALUES (208,12),(51,19)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE post_parent=VALUES(post_parent);

Comment: Ah yeah, I interpreted it as needed multiple post parents tied to a single post. If you're just trying to batch-update a number of posts' parents I don't see anything wrong with using raw SQL.